# Custom Keyboard Shortcut on Mac to Execute Query

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I'm running pgAdmin 4 on my Macbook Pro. The keyboard shortcut to execute the query is the F5 button. I'm looking to map "CMD+r" as a keyboard shortcut in order to execute the query instead of (or in addition to) just the F5 keyboard shortcut.

Is this possible on a Mac? If so, can you explain the steps necessary to do so? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it's possible to set it to "CMD + r", but I was able to set the Execute query shortcut to "Ctrl + r".

Go to "pgAdmin4" in the top menu, hit "Preferences", scroll down to "Query Tool" in the side bar and hit "Keyboard shortcuts". In "Execute query" you have the option to set a hot key with or without any combination of Shift, Ctrl, or Alt/Option. "Ctrl + r" seems intuitive to me.

Another option if you don't want to change the hot key within pgAdmin is to always show the "F keys" on the touch bar. You can set this by going to Apple settings, System settings, Keyboard, Touch Bar settings, and change Touch Bar shows to "F1, F2, etc. Keys"

Hope this helps someone.